# VBA - chrome not working in the background

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I Have a code in VBA with Selenium that does a search on the website and then clicks Download button. The code works fine if I am not making it work in the background. Once I set Chrome to work in the background (adding `.AddArgument ("headless")`) , the code does not download anything. The code is nothing complicated, I just want it to perform the download in the background.

```
Dim d As WebDriver
Set d = New ChromeDriver
Const URL = "Here I put the website"




With d
    .AddArgument ("headless")
    .Start "Chrome"
    .get URL
    .wait 1000
    .FindElementById("Search").SendKeys " Where I insert the search Information "
    .wait 2000
    .FindElementById("search").Click
    .wait 2000
    .FindElementById("download").Click
    .wait 2000

End With
```

Code works fine without the `.AddArgument ("headless")`. If I use it, it does not give me an error but I do not download the `CSV.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the attribute instead such that:

```
.FindElementById("Search").SendKeys
```

becomes

```
.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('#Search').setAttribute('value','Where I insert the search Information');"
```

You may need to alter `'value'` to another attribute e.g. `'textContent'`.

Comment: I will give it a try . I believe that the problem is coming from the clicking of the download button. I did debug print some table elemetns after the search and it does it. For some reason the clicking of the download button is the one not working.

Comment: Is there a similar code that would do the Executescript but for clicking that button?

Comment: .ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('#download').click();"

Comment: Both of the codes you gave work but again if it is headless , they do not work. I am wondering whether it is not downloading as when it is headless it instantly stops using chrome and closes it down, and thus not giving it enough time to download. I tried to use .wait but I do not believe it gets executed. Is there any way to make it wait while in headless?

Comment: it shouldn't finish until you quit the application. Perhaps set up a loop monitoring for increase in file count of download location to know when downloaded.

Comment: Not sure how to do this, I was just manually checking if a folder appears before ( I do apologise as I am still slowly learning ). It is just strange that it works without the headless and not with headless

Comment: Is the website public?

Comment: unfortunately no, I know that this is a problem as you cannot test it yourself :(

Comment: @QHarr Does the downloading of a file works while chrome is headless (selenium VBA)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `window-size()` while setting chrome browser in headless mode.

```
With d
    .AddArgument ("headless")
    .AddArgument "window-size=1920,1080"
    .Start "Chrome"


End With
```

Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: hey, thank you for the suggestion, 
I did try it and again works without the headless but with the headless argument it does not donwload it. I am sure that it does the search bit, but when clicking on the download button, for some reason it does not get exectuted.

I also tried         .Window.Maximize as well but still had no success with it

Comment: Well.Just give a try.With window-size() size can you use actions class to click on the download button.

Comment: Not sure how to use action class, I have never used it before